# Android Progress Bar Launch new activity when get max

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I created a progress bar and I want it to start a new activity when the progress bar reaches 100 . but the code that I have seems to be incorrect. I tried to change it up and I got errors or it just wasn't working. Can someone please help me with what I'm going wrong or give me code that works? Because I have tried so much ways but it doesn't go to the second activity when it's done loading.

MainActivity :

```
package com.example.brandon.territories;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private int progressStatus = 0;
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private ImageView ImageView;
private int progress;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    //Long operation by thread
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (progressStatus < 100) {
                progressStatus += 5;
                //Update progress bar with completion of operation
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                    }
                });
                try {
                    // Sleep for 300 milliseconds.
                    //Just to display the progress slowly
                    Thread.sleep(300);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

class MyProgressBar extends ProgressBar {

    MyProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public MyProgressBar(Context context) { super(context);

    }

    @Override
    public void setProgress(int progress) {
        super.setProgress(progress);
        if (progress == this.getMax()) {
            //Do stuff when progress is max
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items
    //to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

content_main :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@color/background_material_dark"
>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/logo2"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="53dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Loading..."
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="0"
    android:indeterminate="false" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Android Manifest :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_splash"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_second"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

SecondActivity :

```
package com.example.brandon.territories;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;


public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

}

}
```

Comment: why you used 2 times intent filter for launch appliucation.

Comment: At first please modify your manifest

Comment: @RajanBhavsar No i didn't

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya That's the problem , I don't know where to make the changes and even if i do it still won't work.

Comment: You are not even using your custom `MyProgressBar` how do you expect it to call the `startActivity(intent);`

Comment: That's the problem i don't know how .

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to remove the customized ProgressBar subclass, which you aren't using. And make the check of "Max Progress Reached" when you sets the progress in the thread.

The code could be something like this:

```
//Long operation by thread
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        while (progressStatus < progressBar.getMax()) {
            progressStatus += 5;
            //Update progress bar with completion of operation
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                }
            });
            try {
                // Sleep for 300 milliseconds.
                //Just to display the progress slowly
                Thread.sleep(300);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                  Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                  startActivity(intent);
             }
        });
    }
}).start();
```

Hope it helps!